# Why my MariaDB user-defined variables have trash values?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB and I have a problem. This is the code:

https://github.com/analca3/TFG/blob/master/Consultas/extractReplays.sql#L346

I'll explain the problem: I'm using a procedure which has a cursor to iterate over ID's on a table. With each ID, I execute a procedure that extracts some data to a table. But at this procedure I'm using some user-defined variables, and when I use them at second time, I get trash values on them. I know these variables are session-living but I'm resseting all them.

If I execute the internal procedure, close the connection and execute another time, the result table has correct data. What can it be? I'm setting all variables with CROSS JOIN statement. I tried to use local procedure variables but I couldn't use them as counters.